# Get comments from XVIDEOS using rvest [R]

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am a datajournalist and I am trying to scrape all the comments of Xvideos, so it gets easier to find victims of leaked personal videos. I have the following code in R, but I can't go on, because I don't know how to click the button "comment" or how to change the url to show the comments by default. Could you give a hand? Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.xvideos.com/new/1"

links <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `colnames<-`("link") %>%
  filter(str_detect(link, "/video"))
```

Comment: is this a dodgy link?

Comment: @QHarr it's porn if that's what you're referring to as dodgy. When it comes to pornsites it's probably one of the >less dodgy< ones...

Comment: @bardiir  Thanks. Looks like you got the solution covered.

Comment: @QHarr yeah well - came here to close it down as spam after seeing it attracting a lot of views in the charts, discovered it's actually a somewhat legitimate question... so why not try to get some hints down. I mean how many times will you get a chance to visit a porn site and actually do something productive with it 

Comment: Although I'm not sure if parsing comments will really help to identify leaked videos. I'd rather try to open up a database of images from the video streams, like 1 image every 10/30/whatever seconds of video and then do face recognition and matching on that... you could even get value out of that as a separate site that can help you find videos of your favorite porn stars - if that's still a thing :D

Comment: thank you for the help, @bardiir. I will try it. as datajournalist I don't have a strong background in technology. it would be already great to find three victims of this crime after scraping the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why necessarily to use R for this, I would much rather suggest selenium framework to work with for such a workload. This is javascript that does an XHR so it will not be parsable with read html as it will not execute the site code.

But nonetheless you can also reverse engineer the requests - if you want to work with R here is a solution concept that will work:

You get a list of the videos with your code so you should have URLs like this:
`https://de.xvideos.com/video52314867/...`

You can use a regular Expression like `\/video(\d+)\/`to get the ID from there and then request the comment URL:

`POST https://de.xvideos.com/threads/video-comments/get-posts/top/52314867/0/0`

I guess you can see where the ID belongs... this way you will get the video comments as responses directly without executing Javascript.

Comment: I am new at webscraping. What exactly should I write inside the httr::POST or the rvest::request_POST? I have seen some code that they write the login, but I don't know in this case, with a button. Ps: Many users usually identify the women with Facebook link and their name in the comments, and that's the way that I will find and ask for an interview without writing their name in the story, of course :)